# Story Map 3D Web Scene view change

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I am in the process of designing a story map through ArcGIS Online, and I have recently found a way to embed a 3D Web Scene into the story map as a URL. This allows for me to display my 3D data effectively, but it takes away from my ability to set the extent/zoom to certain views when changing tabs within my story map journal. The map as the main stage content allows for different extents to be set to change the view depending on what you want to direct the user to, however since the web scene can only come in as a URL, it does not have the same level of detailing options for setting views.

I want my story journal to update locations based on different tabs similar to the [Mountains of Fire Story Map](http://story.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/?appid=4c77a56bbcd743b69232cf3fd9c7a61c). Does anyone have any idea how I can implement this?

Right now my theory is that they are using a completely different web scene for each of these different locations. Is there any way to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. First you must make slides within the Web Scene. Once you have made the slides of the places that you want the focused view on, then you will save the web scene. Now when you are embedding the URL into the story map, you will put a "#" followed by a "1" at the end of the URL for the 1st slide, a "#" followed by a "2" for the second, and so on.

Example:

http://maps.arcgis.com/home/webscene/viewer.html?webscene=1eef90256d814ad18e7b2f73ca05385c

vs.

http://maps.arcgis.com/home/webscene/viewer.html?webscene=1eef90256d814ad18e7b2f73ca05385c**#1**

This was found on an extension site that was made after an initial esri release on how to incorporate 3D web scenes into story maps. The extension site can be found [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/07/17/using-3d-web-scenes-in-story-maps-redux/).